# Is AWS Managed Prometheus + Grafana a good replacement for in-cluster solution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, prometheus, grafana, monitoring, metrics

I have an EKS cluster that has a slightly modified kube-prometheus running on it for metrics monitoring(includes alertmanager, node exporters, prometheus-operator etc). I am thinking of replacing this setup with the AWS managed Prometheus & AWS managed Grafana. What are the upsides and downsides of making this change? One upside that I believe is this could free up my resources in the cluster to be used for actual applications and might also be a cheaper way of monitoring(not 100% sure on this though).

Comment: "What is better" is opinion based question.

Answer (score -2):

`AWS Managed Prometheus` is fully managed, secure and highly available. Customers only pay for the number of metrics ingested. You get improved scalability, availability and security without having to manage the underlying infrastructure. 
`AWS Managed Graphana` is fully managed, scalable and highly available service providing native integration with AWS services including AWS SSO.
In both cases, you are getting managed services which provides native integration with AWS services and are based on open source standards.